# How to dockerzise beego application

Tags: docker, go, beego

I tried to Dockerize a Beego application, but the HTML rendering is not finding HTML files stored inside the `view/templates` directory.

```sh
FROM golang:1.13
WORKDIR /go/src/fileUpload
COPY . . 
RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go install -v ./...

EXPOSE 8080
# Install server application
CMD ["go", "run", "./main/main.go"]
```

Comment: Can you explain the directory structure of you app better? Perhaps a copy & paste of the output of the `tree` command from the project root?

Comment: Or a quick and dirty: `docker run yourimage /bin/bash -c "apt update && apt install tree && tree"`

Comment: yes.its from root(fileUpload)

Comment: Sorry, the question is not clear enough. Because you use `./main/main.go` to run the app, while according the [docs](https://beego.me/docs/intro/#the-project-structure-of-beego) `.main.go` is in the project root. So there seems to be a different structure...

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the directory containing the templates inside the Docker image.

```
beego.BConfig.WebConfig.ViewsPath = "myviewpath"
```

https://beego.me/docs/mvc/view/view.md#template-directory

**Edit: directory structure**

It is difficult to answer the question, as the directory layout is not clear. However, I can give an example based on [quickstart](https://beego.me/docs/quickstart/new.md):

```
export GOPATH="$HOME/go/src"
bee new quickstart
```

In `$GOPATH/src/quickstart/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM golang:1.13
WORKDIR /go/src/quickstart
COPY . . 
RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go install -v ./...

EXPOSE 8080
# Install server application
CMD ["go", "run", "main.go"]
```

Note that I do not have a directory (`./main`) in front of `main.go`. This is what the structure of the app looks like:

```
tim@sky:~/go/src/quickstart$ tree
.
├── conf
│   └── app.conf
├── controllers
│   └── default.go
├── Dockerfile
├── main.go
├── models
├── routers
│   └── router.go
├── static
│   ├── css
│   ├── img
│   └── js
│       └── reload.min.js
├── tests
│   └── default_test.go
└── views
    └── index.tpl
```

If the `views` directory in you app is in a different place, you need to add the correct path to `main.go` as described in my initial answer.

Comment: is it possible to set in docker file. its working normal in local